# jQuery form validation plugin. make background color only for empty field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, validation

I use jQuery form validation [plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate some form fields. As for now I made css like here:

```
input.error, select.error {
  border: 2px solid red !important;
  }
```

I have some fields that are required and of cause some additional validation is added.
I wonder, is it possible to make background color for empty("required") inputs red but not when they are not empty but not valid.

Comment: red background = empty input; red border = invalid but not empty; no border no background is valid not empty input? And this color coding occurs on submit? Yes?

Comment: Yes. How can I archive this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom validation method and define the required as such:

```
    $.validator.addMethod("custom_required", function(value, element) {
        if ($.trim(value) == "") {
           $(element).addClass('redBg');
           return false;
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass('redBg');
            return true;
        }
    }, "This field cannot be empty");
```

Comment: maybe you missed to `removeClass('redBg')` if everything is Ok ?

Comment: yes definitely, you have to remove the class even when the error is not related to 'required'. i have changed the code.

Comment: Can you take a look http://jsfiddle.net/NfmWW/4/ why Other field is red ? it is not required

Comment: so there was a name collision. you have to change the method name from 'required' to 'custom_required' or something else. updating the code. http://jsfiddle.net/NfmWW/7/

Comment: but why when I start to input data into Email field background doesn`t change? (the field is not empty)

Comment: for some reason putting 'custom_required' in the class list first solved the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/NfmWW/18/

Comment: it is a problem that validation rules can overlap each other. With the help of your answers I`ve solved this problem. Thanks!